# Imagen no se muestra codeblocks SFML

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

Tengo una imagen que deberia mostrarse al correr el programa, el codigo no lanza ningun error pero al correrlo la pantalla se muestra en blanco, al igual que lo haria si nunca hubiera cargado mi imagen, la imagen esta dentro de una carpeta llamada resources ubicada en el proyecto, ya agregue el path en build options > compiler y linker. Algun consejo?

En este archivo defino la ruta:

```
#ifndef DEFINICIONES_H
#define DEFINICIONES_H
#pragma once
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 768
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 1024
#define VISTA_SPLASH_SHOW_TIME 3.0
#define SPLASH_SCENE_BACKGROUND "Resources\res\SplashUces.png"
```

Estas funciones se encargan de cargar y definir texturas:

```
void controladorAssets::cargarTextura(std::string nombre, std::string nombreArchivo)
{
    sf::Texture tex;
    if(tex.loadFromFile(nombreArchivo))
    {
        this->texturas[nombre] = tex;
    }
}

sf::Texture &controladorAssets::getTextura(std::string nombre)
{
    return this->texturas.at(nombre);
}
```

y aca genero la pantalla de inicio:

```
void SplashVista::init()
{
    this->_data->assets.cargarTextura("Vista splash background", SPLASH_SCENE_BACKGROUND);
    this->background.setTexture(this->_data->assets.getTextura("Vista splash background"));
}

void SplashVista::manejarInput()
{
    sf::Event ev;
    while (this->_data->ventana.pollEvent(ev))
    {
        if(sf::Event::Closed == ev.type)
        {
            _data->ventana.close();
        }
    }
}

void SplashVista::update(float dt)
{
    if (this->reloj.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() > VISTA_SPLASH_SHOW_TIME)
    {
        //cambio a vista menu
    }
}

void SplashVista::draw(float dt)
{
    _data->ventana.clear();
    _data->ventana.draw(this->background);
    _data->ventana.display();
}
```

Comment: Por si a caso intenta con la ruta absoluta. Por cierto, qué pasa si `cargarTextura` no puede cargar la textura? `getTextura` intentaría devolver una referencia a nada. Mejor devuelve un puntero, un bool, lanza una excepción o algo para saber que va a suceder algo que no debería y prevenirlo.